# Simple Calaculator in HTML and Javascript does not work

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML (is just a simple pocket calculator):

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SimpleCalculator.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div class="display"><input type="text" readonly size="20" id="dsp"></div>
        <div class="keys">
            <p><input type="button" value="7" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="8" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="9" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="/" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" value="4" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
                <input type="button" value="5" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
                <input type="button" value="6" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
                <input type="button" value="*" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" value="1" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="2" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="3" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="-" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" value="0" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="." onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="+" onclick='getValue(this.value)'></p>
            <p><input type="button" value="C" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="=" onclick='getValue(this.value)'></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the JS file:

```
var s = '';

function getValue(val){
alert(val);

if (val != 'C' && val != '='){s += val;
    document.getElementById("dsp").value+=val;}
if (val === 'C')
    document.getElementById("dsp").value = " ";
if (val === '='){
    alert(document.getElementByVal("dsp").value);
    var res = eval(s);
    document.getElementByVal("dsp").value = res;
}
}
```

The keys are displayed (numbers and math signs), alerts work fine but the evaluation of the expession is not displayed. Where am I wrong ?

Comment: why re-inventing the wheel...? http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut18.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line to use getElementById, not getElementByVal

Answer (score 2):

You should use `getElementById` not `ByVal`, which is not a function.

```js
var s = '';

function getValue(val){

if (val != 'C' && val != '='){s += val;
    document.getElementById("dsp").value+=val;}
if (val === 'C')
    document.getElementById("dsp").value = " ";
if (val === '='){
    alert(document.getElementById("dsp").value);
    var res = eval(s);
    document.getElementById("dsp").value = res;
}
}
```

```html
<h2>Simple Calculator</h2>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div class="display"><input type="text" readonly size="20" id="dsp"></div>
        <div class="keys">
            <p><input type="button" value="7" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="8" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="9" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="/" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" value="4" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
                <input type="button" value="5" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
                <input type="button" value="6" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
                <input type="button" value="*" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" value="1" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="2" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="3" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="-" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
            </p>
            <p><input type="button" value="0" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="." onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="+" onclick='getValue(this.value)'></p>
            <p><input type="button" value="C" onclick='getValue(this.value)'>
               <input type="button" value="=" onclick='getValue(this.value)'></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```